# validate function is not working in Hapi.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, hapi.js

I am new to hapi.js framework , I have made different files for routes and plugins . I have registered the hapi-auth-jwt plugin in a file named hapi-auth.js

Hapi-auth-jwt has functionality of validating the token with some function.

I have added my function named "validate" to my code ... this function is not working...please help me ...

```
'use strict';
const User = require('../Models/user.js');
const config = require('../Config');


let validate = function(request,decodedToken,callback){

var user = User.findOne({},function(err,user){

        if(err)
            throw err;
        return user;    
    });

let error,credentials = user.username || {};

  if(!credentials)
     return callback(null,false,credentials);
  return callback(null,true,credentials);
};

exports.register = function(server, options, next){


server.register(require('hapi-auth-jwt'),(err)=>{

server.auth.strategy('token','jwt',{

    key : config.jwtSecret.key,
    validateFunc : validate,
    verifyOptions:{ algorithms:['HS256'] }
});

});

 next();
};

exports.register.attributes = {
  name: 'hapi-auth-plugin'
 };
```

Comment: check it https://auth0.com/blog/2016/03/07/hapijs-authentication-secure-your-api-with-json-web-tokens/

Comment: why are you setting callback function to a variable, that will not work they way you want it to?

Comment: I am just setting the function definition to a variable validate

Comment: you will never be able to set that variable with async function

Comment: @simon-p-r see this example https://github.com/ryanfitz/hapi-auth-jwt

Comment: @UditKumawat the "user" variable will always be undefined so will always be an empty object

Comment: @simon-p-r even before running mongoose query I have checked for console.log("wroking")....it also not showing..so it means the function is not called

Comment: You need to check your code as not correct

Answer (score 2):

@uditkurmawat

It happens because the request is rejected before entering the validate function. The request must be ends up here
https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-auth-jwt2/blob/master/lib/index.js#L32

You need to assign authorization token before making the request.
Check this: https://github.com/dwyl/learn-json-web-tokens

Comment: so, you are missing assigning token part.

Comment: I left the authorization field in headers :P